# Getting null data when executing LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Book table: 
[image]

From this table, I am trying to get the latest registrationNumber based on the group ID as an input from the user.

So, my query looks like this at the moment:

```
var booksQuery = _context.Books.Where(g => g.GroupId == id)
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.RegistrationNumber).GroupBy(g => g.GroupId);
```

id is the group Id specified by the user. So for example, if id = 15, then I should get the 15:6 as my latest registration number. To do that, I basically grouped by id and ordered the result by descending order. But that is giving me null results. Anyone know  why? I am very new to this LINQ-Entitiy coding.

Comment: Whats the point of the `GroupBy` at the end?  At that point you have a collection of books that only have a GroupId of X, and they are ordered.  Why Group them again?

Comment: @maccettura It's not grouping *again*. You, just as I did, expected to see a `GroupBy` where OP used `Where`.

Comment: @GertArnold correct me if I am wrong, but the initial `Where()` filter condition `(GroupId == id)` means that the `OrderBy` statement will _only_ have elements that have the specified GroupId, then the `GroupBy` at the end will only have _one_ group since it is grouping by GroupId (which we will only have one GroupId)

Comment: @maccettura Ah, OK, if that's what you mean by grouping, yes. Anyway, `FIrstOrDefault()` seems the way to go, provided that there are no numbers like `15:10` etc.

Comment: @GertArnold FirstOrDefault() likely wouldn't work either.  The OP wants all the books that have the specified GroupId.  If you notice the image attached you can see that the first 4 elements all have the same GroupId.  I believe the OP wants all of them (OP feel free to correct me).

Comment: @maccettura, I think I can see why you are saying group by is not necessary. Since I am specifying exactly which group I want, I can see why group by is not needed. So, the registration numbers are sequential and they will reach 15:10 and beyond.

Comment: How do I get the exact 15:6 record in this case? I mean only one record instead of getting the records in descending order and then fetching the first record, I want to get only the 15:6 one in this case.

Comment: @bangbang I would recommend changing your DB schema.  Registration number is currently a string, which means ordering wont work the way you imagine (int ordering and string ordering are entirely different).  Change registration number to just an int, and only store 1, 2, 3, etc,etc. You can build the real registration number with the GroupId field and the RegistrationNumber field (i.e `$"{GroupId}:{RegistrationNumber}"`)

Comment: I see your point. I will do that. So, how will I get just one record? Is there something like max() ?

Comment: Also, instead of converting the registration number to just integers.. can I not rely on the column "Id" to get the latest record based on the specified group ?

Comment: You can, but what's the point of registration number then? If you just need to keep track of latest records in order that they've been added to the database you can just use the ID and remove registration altogether.

Comment: There is a point of using registration number. it's used  as an identifier for each book. I did not want to make it as an ID either because it could be edited as well. That's why I decided to keep a different column for ID. But now that I think through this, I feel that relying on ID is also not gona work because the books can be inserted via the UI by the user in an unordered format. A user can add a 15:11 book  before entering 15:10 book. So ordering by ID will give me the max ID of 15:10 instead of 15:11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others you really should make your registrationNumber field an integer since you are wanting to sort on it.  In the event, you can't make the change, below is a Linq query that basically parses the registration number and converts to an integer to sort on the first and second part by splitting at the colon.  This works for sorting when you have 15:10, etc, as in the string sort 15:6 comes before 15:10

```
 var booksQuery = books.Where(g => g.GroupId == id).ToList();

 var bookWanted = booksQuery   
            .OrderByDescending(g => int.Parse(g.registrationNumber.Split(':')[0]))
            .ThenByDescending(g=> int.Parse(g.registrationNumber.Split(':')[1]))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I try to run it and the only issue is that it's giving me an error saying that it does not like the conversion of string to int happening in the query. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is the error I get: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse

Comment: See my updated answer since you are getting the LINQ to Entities error, first get the list of books that have the exact Group Id you want, and then get the specific book using the ordering query which is outside of Linq to Entities